# Initial condition sensitivity issue in MINLP with Gekko

Tags: gekko

I'm having a problem with sensitivity to initial conditions in an MINLP problem with Gekko. My test case is finding $a$ and $b$ such that $\pi^a/b = \pi^2/6$. So the solution is $a=2$ and $b=6$. I set the initial values of $a$ and $b$ to $a0$ and $b0$ in the code. But i get different solutions depending on what these initial values are. Here are some examples:

```
Result 1: a0 = 5, b0 = 5, a = [6.0], b = [585.0], objective = 0.0015337359503
Result 2: a0 = 5, b0 = 6, a = [5.0], b = [185.0], objective = 0.0092263914506
Result 3: a0 = 2, b0 = 6, a = None, b = None, objective = 0.0
Result 4: a0 = 0, b0 = 0, a = [0.0], b = [0.0], objective = 1e+99
Result 5: a0 = 2, b0 = 5, a = [2.0], b = [6.0], objective = 0.0
```

Result 5 gives the correct solution, but there seems to be many different issues here. Why does result 1 and 2 miss the correct solution? Why does the solver give up when given the correct values? (Result 3). What is going on in result 4? How do i set up Gekko to find the correct solution here, independent of initial values, and keeping lb = 0?

```
import math
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote = False)
m.options.SOLVER = 1 # MINLP

pi = m.Const(math.pi)
c = m.Const(math.pi**2 / 6)

a0 = 5
b0 = 5

a = m.Var(value = a0, lb = 0, ub = 5000, integer = True)
b = m.Var(value = b0, lb = 0, ub = 5000, integer = True)

m.Obj(abs((pi**a)/(b)-c))

try:
    m.solve(disp = False)
except:
    a.value = None
    b.value = None

print(f'Results: a0 = {a0}, b0 = {b0}, a = {a.value}, \
b = {b.value}, objective = {m.options.objfcnval}')
```